# How to integrate paypal with ruby on rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal

Suggest I have User model(devise), this user must be able to pay for some services, using his paypal account. So I want to implement paypal_account:

```
class PaypalAccount < ActiveRecord::base
  attr_accessible #paypal credentials
  ...
  belongs_to :user
end
```

So when user checkout some service, he is redirected to paypal only to confirm this.
If this is posible: what attributes(fields in db) `paypal_accounts` must have?, how to build this request?.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This example will be useful for you https://github.com/nov/paypal-express-sample

Comment: Thanks.. this example was very helpful

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look at the APIs Paypal offers to developers, starting from [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/gs_PayPalAPIs/).

But it can be a long and error-prone task.

IMO the best option is to use the gem who best suits your requirements amongst the several ones you can find on github.

I personally found [this](https://github.com/nov/paypal-express) quite straightforward to use.

Comment: This is the gem with what I am working...The problem was, that I was using the new paypal res-api documentation with this gem. Thanks..